# Checking if $f_n(x)=\sqrt[n]{1+x^n}$ uniformly converges.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, uniform-convergence

$f_n(x)=\sqrt[n]{1+x^n}$. First of all, I have to find its different limits so that I can find $f(x)$. This is where I have a problem: if $x> 1$, then $x\le f_n(x)=f(x)\le 2x$, but I can't get the precise approximation. If $x\le1$, then $\lim\limits_{n\to \infty}{\sqrt[n]{1}}=1\le \lim\limits_{n\to \infty}{f_n(x)}\le \lim\limits_{n\to \infty}{\sqrt[n]{2}}=1$.

What happens when $x$ is between 0 and -1, or when it is <-1?

I could use some help here.

Comment: For $x\ge1$, use $f_n(x)=x\sqrt[n]{1+x^{-n}}$ and fall back to the case $-1<x\le1$.

Comment: What about $x<-1$?

Comment: When $x<-1$, $-1<x^{-1}<0$, so $-1<x^{-n}<0$ when $n$ odd and $0<x^{-n}<1$ when $n$ even. When $-1<x<0$, $-1<x^n<0$ when $n$ odd and $0<x^n<1$ when $n$ even.

Note that the functions fail to converge when $x=-1$. Since the limit is discontinuous but each $f_n$ is continuous, the convergence can't be uniform.

Comment: If x>a>-1 then using logarithmic derivative we can show that the derivatives  are uniformly bounded and so the convergence is uniform. but near -1 the convergence is not uniform if it occurs at all (n needs to be restricted).

Comment: If I am asked if it converges uniformly, the main answer is "no", right?